# A problem arising from reading a lecture on the Yamabe problem of how the Hölder inequality is used

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde

I'm reading [Tawfik - The Yamabe problem](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math580f12/Yamabe.pdf): the PDE is
$$
\Delta \varphi+h(x) \varphi=\lambda f(x) \varphi^{q-1}. \label{1}\tag{1}
$$
**Theorem (Yamabe)**. For $2<q<N=N=2 n /(n-2)$, there exists a $C^{\infty}$ strictly positive $\varphi_{q}$ satisfying \eqref{1} with $\lambda=\mu_{q}$ and $I_{q}\left(\varphi_{q}\right)=\mu_{q}$.

The proof contains several steps:

1. For $2<q \leq N, \mu_{q}$ is finite.
2. Let $\left\{\varphi_{i}\right\}$ be a minimizing sequence such that $\int\limits_{M} f(x) \varphi_{i}^{q} d V=1$: then

   - $\varphi_{i} \in H_{1}$
   - $\varphi_{i} \geq 0$,
   - $\lim _{i \rightarrow \infty} I_{q} \left(\varphi_{i}\right)=\mu_{q}$.
     And we have that the set of the $\varphi_{i}$ is bounded in $H_{1}$.
3. If $2<q<N$, there exists a non-negative function $\varphi_{q} \in H_{1}$ satisfying
   $$
   I_{q}\left(\varphi_{q}\right)=\mu_{q}
   $$
   and
   $$
   \int_{M} f(x) \varphi_{q}^{q} d V=1.
   $$
4. $\varphi_{q}$ satisfies \eqref{1} weakly in $H_{1}$.
5. $\varphi_{q} \in C^{\infty}$ for $2 \leq q<N$ and the functions $\varphi_{q}$ are uniformly bounded for $2 \leq q \leq q_{0}<N$.

**I'm confused about this step.**

The proof is as follows:
*Let $G(P, Q)$ be the Green's function. $\varphi_{q}$ satisfies the integral equation
$$
\begin{aligned}
\varphi_{q}(P)=& V^{-1} \int_{M} \varphi_{q}(Q) d V(Q) \\
&+\int_{M} G(P, Q)\left[\mu_{q} f(Q) \varphi_{q}^{q-1}-h(Q) \varphi_{q}\right] d V(Q)
\end{aligned}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
We know that $\varphi_{q} \in L^{r_{0}}$ with $r_{0}=N$. Since by A 6 part 3 there exists a constant $B$ such that $\lvert G(P, Q)\rvert \leq B[d(P, Q)]^{2-n}$, then according to Sobolev's lemma A1 and its corollary, $\varphi_{q} \in L^{r_{1}}$ for $2<q \leq q_{0}$ with
$$
\frac{1}{r_{1}}=\frac{n-2}{n}+\frac{q_{0}-1}{r+0}-1=\frac{q_{0}-1}{r_{0}}-\frac{2}{n}
$$
and there exists a constant $A_{1}$ such that $\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{r_{1}} \leq A_{1}\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{r_{0}}^{q-1}$. By induction we see that $\varphi_{q} \in L^{r_{k}}$ with
$$
\frac{1}{r_{k}}=\frac{q_{0}-1}{r_{k-1}}-\frac{2}{n}=\frac{\left(q_{0}-1\right)^{k}}{r_{0}}-\frac{2}{n} \frac{\left(q_{0}-1\right)^{k}-1}{q_{0}-2}
$$
and there exists a constant $A_{k}$ such that $\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{r_{k}} \leq A_{k}\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{r_{0}}^{(q-1)^{k}}$. If for $k$ large enough, $1 / r_{k}$ is negative, then $\varphi_{q} \in L_{\infty}$. Indeed suppose $1 / r_{k-1}>0$ and $1 / r_{k}<0$. Then $$
\frac{q_{0}-1}{ r_{k-1}}-\frac{2}{n}<0
$$ and Hölder's inequality A4 applied to \eqref{2} yields $\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{\infty} \leq C\left\lVert_{q}\right\rVert_{r_{k-1}}^{q-1}$ where $C$ is a constant. There exists a $k$ such that
$$
\frac{1}{r_{k}}=\left(q_{0}-1\right)^{k}\left[\frac{1}{r_{0}}-\frac{2}{n\left(q_{0}-2\right)}\right]+\frac{2}{n\left(q_{0}-2\right)}<0
$$
because $n\left(q_{0}-2\right)<2 r_{0}=2 N$, since $q_{0}<N=\frac{2 n}{n-2}$. Moreover, there exists a constant $A_{k}$ which does not depend on $q \leq q_{0}$ such that
$$
\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{\infty} \leq A_{k}\left\lVert\varphi_{q}\right\rVert_{N}^{(q-1)^{k}}.
$$*

**I'm confused why for $k$ large enough, $1 / r_{k}$ is negative, then $\varphi_{q} \in L_{\infty}$ and how the Hölder inequality is applied to \eqref{2}.**

The Hölder inequality is stated as follows:
**Proposition A4 (Hölder's inequality)**. Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. If $f \in$ $L^{r}(M) \cap L^{q}(M)$, $1 \leq r<q \leq \infty$, then $f \in L^{p}$ for $p \in[r, q]$ and
$$
\lVert f\rVert_{p} \leq\lVert f\rVert_{r}^{a}\lVert f\rVert_{q}^{1-\alpha}
$$
with $a=\dfrac{1 / p-1 / q}{1 / r-1 / q}$.

Comment: In the statement of Hölder's inequality, shouldn't the exponent on $\lVert f\rVert_q$ be $1 - a$, not $1 - \alpha$?

Comment: In equation (1), what are the assumptions on the functions $f$ and $h$? Are they assumed to be $L^\infty$?

Comment: Also, what is $q_0$?

Comment: Thanks for answering! Yes it's 1-$a$, both $f$ and $h$ are $C^{\infty}$. For $q_{0}$, it just  come out of nowhere. In my view, from the proof which said that By induction we see that $\varphi_{q} \in L^{r_{k}}$ and there exists $k$ such that $1 / r_{k-1}>0$ and $1 / r_{k}<0$, then we can assume that $1 / r_{k-1}$ is small enough(by changing $q_{0}$), then $\varphi_{q} \in L^{r_{k-1}}$ means $\varphi_{q} \in L^{\infty}$. This is just my general thought, which is not strict.

Comment: This lecture is in aubin's book Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Application of Holder's inequality

Notice that the estimate on the Green's function means that
$$ \int |G(P,Q)|^\alpha ~dQ $$
is bounded whenever $\alpha < \frac{n}{n-2}$ (and the bound can be taken to be uniform; that is independent of $P$).
By Holder's inequality, we have
$$ \int G(P,Q) F(Q) ~dQ \leq \|G(P,-)\|_{L^\alpha} \|F\|_{L^\beta} $$
when $\beta^{-1} = 1 - \alpha^{-1}$. To ensure that the first term is bounded, we need $\alpha < \frac{n}{n-2}$ as described above; this means that $\beta^{-1} < 1 - \frac{n-2}{n} = \frac{2}{n}$.

So applying to equation (2) (noting that $h$ and $f$ are smooth, bounded, and can be discarded), we see that if $\varphi$ is such that both $\varphi\in L^\beta$ and $\varphi^{q-1} \in L^{\beta'}$ with $\beta, \beta' > \frac{n}{2}$, then we can apply the chain of reasoning above to conclude that $\varphi$ is uniformly bounded.

By assumption $q - 1 > 1$; if $\varphi^{q-1}\in L^{\beta'}$ then $\varphi\in L^{(q-1)\beta'}$. This means that we only need:

> if $\varphi^{q-1} \in L^{\beta'}$ with $\beta' > \frac{n}2$, then the equation will guarantee that $\varphi\in L^\infty$.

This final condition can be re-written as $\varphi \in L^\beta$ for some $\beta > \frac{n}{2} (q-1)$. So you just need to argue somehow that $\varphi$ can be taken to have this degree of integrability.

#### Iteration process

Pretty much your intuition is correct. The idea is that solving equation (1), if you know that $\varphi$ is a priori in $L^\beta$, with $\beta < \frac{n}2(q-1)$, then the Sobolev inequality will tell you that
$$ \varphi \in L^{\gamma}, \quad \gamma = \frac{n \beta }{n(q-1) - 2\beta} $$
**Our hope is that starting with $\varphi\in L^\beta$, we can improve it to some $L^\gamma$ for $\gamma > \beta$. And repeating this improvement should eventually get us above the threshold $\frac{n}2(q-1)$.**

Examining this $\gamma$, we see that (under still the assumption that $\beta < \frac{n}2(q-1)$)
$$ \gamma > \beta \iff \frac{n}{n(q-1) - 2\beta} > 1 \iff 2 + \frac{2\beta}{n} > q $$
**In particular**: if we start the iteration process with the first step such that $\gamma > \beta$, then for all subsequent steps we will continue to get improvements from the process.

For the first step, we have $\beta = \frac{2n}{n-2}$ by Sobolev embedding since we pre-supposed $\varphi\in H^1$. So if we know that
$$ q < 2 + \frac{2\beta}{n} = 2 + \frac{4}{n-2} = \frac{2n}{n-2} $$
we can guarantee that during the iteration process, **starting from initial knowledge that $\varphi\in H^1$**, that at every step we will improve that integrability of $\varphi$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! You mean that, if  $\varphi \in L^{\beta}$ for some $\beta>\frac{n}{2}(q-1)$ then we can get that $\varphi \in L^{\infty}$. So we start with $L^{\beta_{0}}$, with $\beta_{0}<\frac{n}{2}(q-1)$. And the iteration step is $\beta_{k}=\frac{n \beta_{k-1}}{n(q-1)-2 \beta_{k-1}}$ then $\frac{1}{\beta_{k}}=\left(q-1\right)^{k}\left[\frac{1}{\beta_{0}}-\frac{2}{n\left(q-2\right)}\right]+\frac{2}{n\left(q-2\right)}$, and from the fact that $q<\frac{2 n}{n-2}$ we have $\frac{1}{\beta_{0}}-\frac{2}{n\left(q-2\right)}<0$ we can find a $k$ such that $\beta_{k} >\frac{n}{2}(q-1)$

Comment: @TeenFromAlishan pretty much. (I didn't check your algebra.) The idea is that you get monotonicity in the gain of integrability as soon as $q < 2 + \frac{2\beta_0}{n}$. (If the power of the nonlinearity is too high, the argument fails at the first step.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it. But I'm still confused how to get $\int|G(P, Q)|^{\alpha} d Q$ is bounded whenever $\alpha<\frac{n}{n-2}$ from $|G(P, Q)|<k r^{2-n}$ for $n>2$, could you give me some hints.

Comment: @TeenFromAlishan the function $1/|x|^\alpha$ is locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^d$ when $d > \alpha$; and the manifold $M$ is compact, so local integrability gives integrability.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These help me a lot. @Willie Wong

Comment: Hey @Willie Wong, sorry to bother again, I think I 'm still confused about the part that how the $L^{\infty}$ norm of $\varphi$ is bounded. From the iteration $\frac{1}{\beta_{k}}=(q-1)^{k}\left[\frac{1}{\beta_{0}}-\frac{2}{n(q-2)}\right]+\frac{2}{n(q-2)}$ and $\left\|\varphi\right\|_{\beta_{k}} \leq A_{k}\left\|\varphi\right\|_{\beta_{0}}^{(q-1)^{k}}$. Is it because we can sent $r_{k}$ to $\infty$? and since we have bound of $H^{1}$ norm so we get the bound of $L^{\beta_{0}}$ norm?

Comment: It's the part of applying Prop.A4  in this lecture.

Comment: @TeenFromAlishan: no, you just iterate until the FIRST time $\beta_k$ becomes larger than $n(1-q)/2$. Since the iteration process is a strictly increasing map of the exponents, this will be attained after finitely many iterations.

Comment: Thanks, I fully understand this part now, I was stuck with the uniform bound part but now it seems much more clear for me.@Willie Wong